# global sections on invertible sheaves over prjective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a integral closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ with $n\geq2$. Let $i:X\to \mathbb{P}$ be the inclusion morphism. Assume $X$ is defined by quadratic relations (or more generally, relations of degree $\geq2$). Let $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}_X(1)=i^*{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)}$. There is a canonical map $$\Gamma(\mathbb{P},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)) \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}).$$

It is easy to show this map is injective. One way to see this is by using the short exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{I}(1)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)\to i_*\mathcal{L}\to 0$ and the fact $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{I}(1))=0$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the ideal sheaf that defines $X$.

Here is my question: Is this map always surjective? If so, then how to see that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not surjective in general. For the simplest example, take $X$ to be the closed embedding $\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^3$, given by $(u^4, u^3t, ut^3, t^4)$. Then $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))$ is four dimensional and $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{L})$ is five dimensional.

Comment: @Mohan7, Thanks. Do you know any condition on $X$ to assure the map to be surjective?I think your example has a cubic relation. So  If we assume the defining relations are all quadractic, then is the map surjective?